# ripple effect on child views not working

Tags: android, android-layout

this is the layout code

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></RelativeLayout>
```

ripple works only outside child views. how to achieve ripple to effect whole layout including childviews?

Comment: Set "android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"" of them as well.

Comment: So you want the Child Views to have their individual ripples when they are clicked, and the RelativeLayout to have the ripple when anything is clicked?

Comment: @Rachit no i want only one ripple throughout the layout

Comment: So just setting the android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" will do that. What is not working for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try changing the

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

to

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

This will make the ripple appear on top of the RelativeLayout, so all your ChildViews will also get the ripple over them.

The difference is this:

[image: Click on two RelativeLayouts]

In the top RelativeLayout the background is set as selectableItemBackground, whereas in the bottom the foreground is set as selectableItemBackground

Comment: thank you , android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" works single ripple throughout layout