# Tap ripple effect for API lesser than 21

Tags: android, kotlin, android-relativelayout, ripple

Hello there I am new to kotlin I have been facing a very strange problem. I have a simple ListView populated with some child layouts!
My ListView Tag in XML is:

```
          <ListView
            android:id="@+id/invoicesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

My Adapter is:

```
class InvoicesListAdapter(context: Context, activity: Activity, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<InvoicesListModel>) : ArrayAdapter<InvoicesListModel>(context, resource, list) {

    var list: ArrayList<InvoicesListModel> = list
    var activity: Activity? = null

    init {
        this.activity = activity
    }

    private class ViewHolder(row: View?) {
        var serviceName: BakcellTextViewNormal? = null
        var endirimValue: BakcellTextViewNormal? = null
        var miqdarValue: BakcellTextViewNormal? = null
        var vahidValue: BakcellTextViewNormal? = null
        var mablaqValue: BakcellTextViewNormal? = null
        var camiValue: BakcellTextViewNormal? = null

        init {
            this.serviceName = row?.findViewById(R.id.serviceValue)
            this.endirimValue = row?.findViewById(R.id.endirimValue)
            this.miqdarValue = row?.findViewById(R.id.miqdarValue)
            this.vahidValue = row?.findViewById(R.id.vahidValue)
            this.mablaqValue = row?.findViewById(R.id.mablaqValue)
            this.camiValue = row?.findViewById(R.id.camiValue)
        }//init ends
    }// class ViewHolder ends

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View?
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        if (convertView == null) {
            val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invoices_list_layout, null)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view?.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            view = convertView
            viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        var listModel = getItem(position)
        viewHolder.serviceName!!.text=listModel.serviceName
        viewHolder.miqdarValue!!.text=listModel.miqdarValue
        viewHolder.vahidValue!!.text=listModel.vahidValue
        viewHolder.mablaqValue!!.text=listModel.mablaqValue
        viewHolder.endirimValue!!.text=listModel.endirimValue
        viewHolder.camiValue!!.text=listModel.camiValue

        //send arrow click

        return view as View
    }//getview ends
}//class ends
```

My Adapter/ListView Items Layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--nested container-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/childLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!--col1-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.2">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal
                            android:id="@+id/serviceValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="Blackberry Service"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--col2-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal
                            android:id="@+id/miqdarValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="12345"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--col3-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal
                            android:id="@+id/vahidValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="saat:den:san"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--col4-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal
                            android:id="@+id/mablaqValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="98.2"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGray"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--col5-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3.3">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal
                            android:id="@+id/endirimValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="0.0"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--col6-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal
                            android:id="@+id/camiValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="1125.7"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--//nested container-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_45sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_45sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorSeperator"></View>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that I want to show the ripple when I tap onto the Relative Layout with id=ripple!
I know I can do it setting:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

on the required Layout!
But whenever I register any click listener on the Relative Layout with id=ripple, it stops showing the ripple effect!

I am testing it on LG G3 with Android 5.0 Lollipop and I want the Android Devices with Android Versions 19+ should show the ripple effect.

I must use

```
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
```

to show the ripple effect, Can somebody please identify it for me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130359/ripple-effect-on-child-views-not-working

Comment: tried that too, not working

Comment: I think that problem can be with your com.es.b2bbakcell.widgets.textwidgets.BakcellTextViewNormal views. I changed this items for simple TextView and ripple effect worked on every item in the list with android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground". Tested on Android 8.0.

Comment: Tested on Android 4.4 - not worked. I think it should not work on Android API < 21.

Comment: Apparently, the ripple effect is exclusive only to API 21 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Try `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`

Comment: it requires 21+ android Version

Comment: No it doesn't. I use it in one app that has min 17

Comment: Is it that the layout is cluttered by other views and you just can't see the ripple?